# scrollTo is undefined on animated ScrollView

Tags: react-native

When using `Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView)` to create an animated `ScrollView` it's not longer possible to use `scrollTo`.

```js
    const AnimatedScrollView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);

    <AnimatedScrollView ref={(ref) => this.list = ref}>
      <View style={{height: 1000}} />
    </AnimatedScrollView>
```

Calling `this.list.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0})` gives the following error:

`_this.list.scrollTo is not a function`

It works fine on a normal ScrollView. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

@max23_ 's answer might work for now, but is not the correct way of doing it - as a rule of thumb, we should never access private variables directly as these are often subject to change. (edit: no disrespect :-) )

Due to [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9944), the new and future-proof way of getting the wrapped component's `ref` is to use the `getNode()` utility method, as accessing private variables (prepended with `_`) is not safe from future API changes.

So, the new way of doing it is

```js
    ref={c => (this.myRef = c)}
```

and then when calling the method, doing

```js
    this.myRef.getNode().scrollTo({
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    });
```

:-)

Comment: Nice finding on the `getNode()`. I think it can be rewritten to `ref = {c => this.myRef = c.getNode()}` so you wouldn't need to always call `getNode()`.

Comment: I actually tried that, but got an undefined error - didn't have time to debug it at the time, but feel free to edit the answer if you can get it working :-)

Comment: Using an animated scrollview I was stumped trying to figure this out, thanks for the info. One caveat is that `ref = {ref => this.scrollView = ref.getNode()}` doesn't work for me but `this.scrollView.getNode().scrollTo()` works fine.

Comment: scrollToOffset() doesn't work for me, only scrollTo()

Comment: getting this => getNode is not a function

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth - See my answer to max23_'s comment above

Answer (score 23):

Try this to get the ref of the component returns from `Animated.createAnimatedComponent` method:

```js
ref={(ref) => this.list = ref._component}
```

Then, calling the below should work:

```js
this.list.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0})
```

Comment: So whenever I use this solution, I always get error's when trying to use this.setState. I got around it by setting ref like this: `ref='scrollRef'` and then using the scrollTo function by calling this: `this.refs.scrollRef._component.scrollTo`

Comment: i got the same problem, i used flatList, for me path looks like ref._component._listRef._scrollRef

Answer (score 12):

Building on the answer from @jhm - the new, recommended way to create a ref to a component since React 16.3 is to use `React.createRef()` as mentioned by @cyqui.

With a normal (note: non-animated) component, we'd simple create a ref to the `ScrollView` in the recommended way:

```js
scrollView = React.createRef();

<ScrollView
  ref={this.scrollView}>
```

and use static methods as such:

```js
this.scrollView.current.scrollTo({x: number, y: number, animated: true|false})
```

**EDIT: As of RN 0.62 the below is [no longer necessary](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0620)**

However, when working with an `Animated` component, we're moving into [direct manipulation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/direct-manipulation) which requires us to get the native node of the component before calling any static methods. Therefore, you'd end up with the following:

```js
scrollView = React.createRef();

<Animated.ScrollView
  ref={this.scrollView}>
```

```js
this.scrollView.current.getNode().scrollTo({x: number, y: number, animated: true|false})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another answer as both "getNode" and "_component" solution didn't work for me. I'm using react native 0.57. Manage to make it work using scrollToOffset

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.refs.listRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: 0,  animated: false })
}

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList ref="listRef" ... />
  }
};
```

Comment: Is this the animated ScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

If RN >= 0.59 (maybe earlier) and the following Ref setup:

`const ScrollViewX = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);`

```
  _scrollView = React.createRef();

<ScrollViewX
      ref={this._scrollView}>
```

You can manually scroll an Animated component this way :

`this._scrollView.current._component.scrollTo({x: number, y: number, animated: true|false})`

(ScrollToOffset is deprecated and probably removed in 0.6)